# Edit dataframe on one tab and have it load correctly on another in R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a proof of concept where the user can edit a dataframe on one tab and then view it on another. I would like to have the user be able to view many different visualizations with the same base data so putting everything on one tab wont do it for me.

My solution thus far is to have a "save button" that writes to the global scope so that the data can be accessed across tabs. However, due to lazyeval this only works if the user has not yet clicked on a tab before ie shiny does not know that anything has changed on that tab.

For the code below, heres what happens:
1. Filter the data using the slider
2. press save
3. go to the second tab (it works)
4. repeat steps 1 and 2
5. go back to the second tab (it doesnt work)

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Server Code

```
function(input, output){

# on initilization  
master$date <- Sys.time()
master$dataframe <- mtcars

output$tab1<-renderDataTable({
   df<-master$dataframe
   display <- df%>%filter(disp > input$slider)
    temp<<-display

 })

 observeEvent(input$save, {
   master$date <<- Sys.time()
   master$dataframe <<- temp
 })

 #tab two
 output$tab2 <- renderDataTable({
 master$dataframe
 })
 }
```

UI Code

```
 sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
 sidebarMenu(
 menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
 menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets",
         badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green")
  )
 )

body <- dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
    sliderInput("slider", "Choose a number", 0, 200, 50),
    dataTableOutput("tab1"),
    actionButton("save", "Save Filter")
),

tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
      dataTableOutput("tab2")
 )
)
)

dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
 sidebar,
 body
)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens when "it doesn't work"?   Is the data wrong, does the tab freeze, does shiny crash?  If the data is not what you expect explain how.

Comment: Nothing freezes or crashes. The issue is that the data does not update because shiny does not reevaluate the reactive.

Comment: So you need to explain all the details in your question, not in the comments.  Are you saying tab2 is always the full mtcars?  I think you keep reloading it rather than testing to see if you have already created a modified version.